# Using solar mass symbol in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I want to insert the solar mass symbol in a `ggplot2` legend, but I do not know how.

I'v tried so far the `expression()` and `TeX()` functions (the last one is a function of the package latex2exp) but none of then have solved my problem.

Here is a sample of what I was trying to do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)

ggplot() + 
  labs(x = expression(Log(Age/yr)),
       y = TeX("$\\odot$"))
```

Comment: What is a `TeX` function?

Comment: Sorry, it's a function of the package latex2exp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's not the right (and elegant) answer but the following code worked

```
  labs(y = expression(Log(M[stellar]/M['☉'] ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hate to give a partial answer, but if you wanted say give the mass of the Earth, you'd use the following:

```
labs(y = expression(symbol("M"["\305"])))
```

Don't know what to change the `"\305"` to, though to get the right character.